# How to get rounded corners on NSScrollView to work with NSRulerView

Tags: cocoa, calayer, rounded-corners, nsscrollview, rulers

I’m having some difficulty getting an `NSTextView` embedded in an `NSScrollView` with a horizontal `NSRulerView` to play well with a rounded corner mask. I’ve created a simple test application to localize the issue.

First, it appears there are basically two ways to get rounded corners on an `NSScrollView`. The first is to use a `CAShapeLayer` and set it’s path property to the desired rounded rectangle bezier path. The second is to set a `CALayer`’s `cornerRadius` property to the desired value, and then set it’s `backgroundColor` property to any color with a 1.0 alpha (such as solid black). Either of these layers can then be used to set the `NSScrollView`’s backing layer’s `mask` property, after making it layer-backed via `setWantsLayer:`. Though I get some drawing artifacts when I apply it directly to the `NSScrollView`'s backing layer. So instead, I apply the mask to the `NSScrollView`’s superview's backing layer. The superview itself is just a simple container view.

Now, the problem arises when we show the ruler view and begin interacting with it. The ruler view itself looks great, it has rounded corners because of the mask applied above. However, when I start to add and drag markers, they are invisible until I release the mouse, making it very difficult to position markers. Also, the standard vertical marker lines do not appear while dragging.

I’ve confirmed that this is occurring due to the presence of the mask. When I disable the mask, the `NSRulerView` behaves normally.

So the question is, how can I get `NSRulerView` and `NSScrollView`’s rounded corners to play well together?

It looks almost as if the mask layer is somehow obscuring the temporary drawing that’s occurring in the `NSRulerView` during mouse-drag tracking. If this is the case, how do I get the `NSRulerView` to perform it’s drawing above everything else? Making it and all other views layer-backed, as well as positioning the `NSRulerView` above all sibling views (for good measure) doesn’t seem to have any effect.

I’ve also tried subclassing `NSTextView` to override the delegate method `rulerView:willMoveMarker:` (and others) to force drawing, but it seems to draw the marker in a weird location, near the bottom left of the window, nowhere near the `NSRulerView`, even after ensuring I’m in the right coordinate system. I suspect this is a drawing artifact, though, since forcing it to draw elsewhere has no effect.